# jwplayer with same edits

Tags: php, youtube, jwplayer

im using jwplayer for my script to get youtube videos

same edits i needed for my site to make player work good

same videos in youtube have tips so if i add it to my site it show tips without close button

how can i disable tips from youtube to stop it

[exmaple for tips](http://3eba.com/t891)

other request how i make video preview from youtube like youtube player in jwplayer

and how to display related files (it work with old jwplayer but new jwplayer need same edit for make related work)

my sctipt is onaracde

and this is old related.php

```
<?php
/**
 * onArcade 2.2.3
 * Copyright © 2006-2009 Hans , All Rights Reserved
 **
 * ONARCADE IS NOT FREE SOFTWARE!
 * http://www.onarcade.com
 **/

session_start();

define('PAGE', 'related');

require ('includes/config.php');

header ('Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8');

echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<videolist>
<title>مشابهه فيديوهات:</title>';

    $file_id = (int) $_GET['f']; // get file id

    // Get file information from database... this is one big and ugly query
    $file_sql = "
        SELECT
            file.*,
            cat.name AS category_name, cat.permissions, cat.status AS category_status";
    if ($settings['added_by'] == 1)
        $file_sql .= ", ad.username AS adder_username";
    $file_sql .= "
        FROM
            ". $tbl_prefix ."files AS file
            LEFT JOIN ". $tbl_prefix ."categories AS cat ON (cat.catid = file.category)";
    if ($settings['added_by'] == 1)
        $file_sql .= " LEFT JOIN ". $tbl_prefix ."users AS ad ON (ad.userid = file.added_by)";
    $file_sql .= "
        WHERE file.fileid = ". $file_id ." && file.status = '1'
        LIMIT 1";

    $file_query = mysql_query($file_sql); // run query
    $file_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($file_query);

    // get related files from database
    if ($settings['related_files'] == 1) {
        $related_query = mysql_query("SELECT fileid, title, description, icon, iconlocation, timesplayed FROM ". $tbl_prefix ."files WHERE category = ". $file_row['category'] ." && status ='1' && fileid != ". $file_id ." ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ". $settings['max_related_files']);
        while ($related_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($related_query))
            $txt['related'][] = array (
                'fileid'        =>  $related_row['fileid'],
                'title'         =>  $related_row['title'],
                'url'           =>  fileurl($related_row['fileid'],$related_row['title']),
                'description'   =>  $related_row['description'],
                'image'         =>  file_image_url($related_row['icon'], $related_row['iconlocation'])
            );
    }

        foreach ($txt['related'] as $related) {
        echo '
            <video id="'. $related['fileid'] .'">
            <title>'. $related['title'] .'</title>
            <thumb>', (str_replace('hqdefault.jpg', 'default.jpg',  $related['image'])) ,'</thumb>
            <url>'. $related['url'] .'</url>
            </video>';
        }   
echo '
</videolist>';

?>
```

and this is jwplayer settings file

```
    <div id="resize_file" style="width:{$width}px;height:{$height}px;">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="player/jwplayer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("container").setup({
            file:"{$file_url}",
            image: "{$file_image}",
            autostart: "true",
            aboutlink:"http://elfnon.com",
            abouttext:"elfnon.CoM",
            allowscriptaccess:"always",
            height: {$height},
            width: {$width},
            wmode:"opaque",
            volume:"100",
            icons:"true",
            bufferlength:"900",
            related: {
                file: '{$siteurl}/jw6-related.xml',
                onclick: 'link'
                        },
            modes:[
                { type:'html5' }
            ]
        });
jwplayer("container").onPlay(function () {
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('container-holder').className = '';
    }, 1000);
});
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Under:

```
autostart: "true",
```

Add:

```
primary: "flash",
```

You only get the YouTube annotations in their API in HTML5 mode, but Flash mode will make them disabled.

Comment: But when i open from phone it show video normaly or this make same problem?

Comment: It will fall back to html5 on mobile and display properly. Try it, it will work.

Comment: and about make preview for videos from youtube and related files?

Comment: ethan can u help me for make retaled files and share plugin working? example here but retaled not work http://3eba.com/t891

Comment: If you use a YouTube video, the Preview image will be automatically generated using the YouTube API. No, you cannot hide the Google Ads, as they are required by YouTube's use of there API. Here is how to set up Sharing - http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1409823-social-sharing-overlay, here is how to set up Related - http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1409745-display-related-videos

Comment: sharing not show < what is this problem? i just add sharing: {}, to test it but not showing!! and other related files not show 2 !!

Comment: and if i add logo to jw player video not work on phone and show msg null!!

Comment: don't know what the version i got from friend but i think it ads edition so i need another version or what?

Comment: You need at least Pro for Sharing, Premium for Related. So if you don't have that paid edition, those features will not work.

Comment: You are going to have to provide his email address he used for the order so I can look up his paid purchase in our license database.

Comment: cant access to his email cuz he travel at now so how i know heis verison with my files? i forget sharing work at phone but icon not showing at computer so why that?

Comment: You are going to need to let me know the email used for the order before I can help you further.

Comment: then we well wait him to back to give me his email